# Calculate $7^{154} \pmod{341}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

how to calculate remainder of $7^ {154}$ when it is divided by $341$.
Could you please state which method or theorem to use.

Comment: **Hint** $ $ By Fermat $\,7^{30}\equiv 1\bmod 11\ \&\ 31,\,$ so also $\!\bmod 341,\,$ so $\bmod 341\!:\ 7^{154}\equiv 7(7^3)\equiv 7(2)\,$ by $\,154\equiv 4\pmod{\!30}$ and [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242).

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem, and the Chinese Remainder theorem.  To get started $341 = 31\times 11$ and $31$ and $11$ are both prime.

Comment: You can also use Eulers theorem and educated guessing with successive squaring.  $\phi(341)=\phi(31)\phi(11) = 300$ so $7^{150}$ is probably $\equiv \pm 1\pmod {341}$ and testing $7^k$ were $k|150$ particularly $k=3,5,10$ will likely be useful. $7^2=49$ and $7^3=(50-1)7=350-7=343\equiv 2$. $7^{30}\equiv 1024\equiv  1$. So $7^{150}\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, that $7^3 = 343$ and $341*3=1023$, so $2^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{341}$, then

$$7^{154} \equiv 7 * 2^{51} \equiv 7 * 1 * 2 = 14 \pmod{341}$$

Comment: Thanks.... Its a silly question. I couldn't get it.

Comment: it should be 2^10≡1(mod341) instead of 2^10≡1(mod343) Thanks